# showInputDialog makes "if" work wrong

Tags: java, input, joptionpane

I'm making simple version of Minesweeper and have a problem with this part of code:

```
if ((uncover == 0) && inGame) {
        inGame = false;
        long elapsedTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)/1000;
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Congrats, you won! \n Your result is "
                + elapsedTime + " sec. Please, enter your name: ");
        statusbar.setText("Game won");
        }
    else if (!inGame)
        statusbar.setText("Game lost");
```

So here is the thing: if game is won, it shows input dialog, but status bar is still changing to "Game lost". And if I remove or comment this

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Congrats, you won! \n Your result is "
                + elapsedTime + " sec. Please, enter your name: ");
```

everything works just fine. What's the problem with that?

Comment: One thing that I notice right off the bat you are not catching the input from the input dialog at all.  you need to catch the String input from the dialog.

Comment: What happens if you move the `statusbar.setText("Game won");` above `JOptionPane.show...`?

Comment: I don't think catching the input causes the problem, it is somewhere else. From where do you call this code? is it an action listener?

Comment: What happens when you move your statusbar.setText() ahead of the JOptionPane.showInputDialog?

Comment: Do you wait until you type your name and press OK, even after pressing OK you see game lost?

Comment: kinbiko, adamc78, it's just the same.

Comment: Konstantinos Chalkias, it's called in paintComponent function. Status bar updates just after the input window appears.

Comment: It's been a long time since I dealt with Swing, but I'm pretty sure those `setText` calls need to be on the EDT.

Comment: Your basic `if` block seems to work fine for me, I think the issue is somewhere else in your code. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the input and you are not filling in all the inputdialog options which could be causing warnings or compile errors.

```
String getInput = "";
getInput = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
        null,
        "Congrats, you won! \n Your result is "
            + elapsedTime + " sec. Please, enter your name: ",
        null,
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
        null,
        null,
        null);
```

Hope this helped

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still working like before. In fact, status bar updates to "Game lost" just after the dialog windows appears, even before I write anything in it.

Comment: Then you need to fix how uncover is counted and or inGame is set.

Comment: I guess they are fine, I just can't understand: if input dialog window appears, it means, that the first branch of "if" is executed, how then it's executing the code if "else if" branch?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using [`JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)).

Comment: okay you have a two condition if statement but only a 1 condition else statement.

Comment: I am sorry about the last comment very curt. This is a minesweeper game there are two options for end of game, you hit a mine and lose or you clear all the squares that can be and win.  Where does the inGame and !inGame come up in your code to be set